# Android EditText not editable

Tags: android

I have a 2 activities with edittexts on them the first activity work fine but the second activity's EditText is focused but I can't edit it nor can I click the button on it.

Also everything works in the emulator but not when I install it on the device. (The keyboard popup also does not come up in the second activity where as it does in the first activity)

Below is the code for the1st and second activity
First Activity Class

```
    package com.rohan.rohan_pc.sportappnew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edtEmail, edtPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Initialize components
        edtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);

        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (edtEmail.getText().toString().length() > 0 && edtPassword.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new ConnecterClass());
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Connect to the DB
    private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<ConnecterClass, Long, JSONArray>
    {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ConnecterClass... params) {
            // Execute in background

            return params[0].usrLogin(edtEmail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            if (jsonArray != null) {
                JSONObject json = null;
                try {
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    if (edtEmail.getText().toString().equals(json.getString("email"))) {
                        if (edtPassword.getText().toString().equals(json.getString("pass"))) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);

                            //Pass the school_id
                            intent.putExtra("SCHOOL_ID", json.getInt("school_id"));

                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to login ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //login(edtEmail.getText().toString(),""
/*
                //Got to second screen if login is successful
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AfterLogin.class);

                //Pass the table name through
                intent.putExtra("CLIENT_DB", clientDB);

                startActivity(intent);

                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity Class

```
> package com.rohan.rohan_pc.sportappnew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class SearchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText edtFName, edtLName, edtIDNum;
    ListView listViewSearch;

    String sFName, sLName, sIDNum;

    int school_id;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        edtFName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFirstName);
        edtLName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtLastName);
        edtIDNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtIDNum);

        Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

        listViewSearch = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);

        //Initialize the default values for the search criteria variables
        sFName = "";
        sLName = "";
        sIDNum = "";

        //Load school_id
        school_id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SCHOOL_ID");

        if(edtFName.requestFocus()) { getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE); }

        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(edtFName.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    sFName = edtFName.getText().toString().trim();
                }

                if(edtLName.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    sLName = edtLName.getText().toString().trim();
                }

                if(edtIDNum.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    sIDNum = edtIDNum.getText().toString().trim();
                }

                new SearchAllCustomers().execute(new ConnecterClass());

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    //Search in the background

    public void setListViewArray(final JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        this.listViewSearch.setAdapter(new Search_ListView_Adapter(jsonArray, this));

        //Setup what happens when a user clicks on a searched item
        this.listViewSearch.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try{
                    JSONObject clickedItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);

                    Intent askActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AskActivity.class);
                    askActivity.putExtra("IDNUM", clickedItem.getString("idnum"));
                    askActivity.putExtra("SCHOOL_ID", clickedItem.getInt("school_id"));

                    startActivity(askActivity);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Connect to the DB
    private class SearchAllCustomers extends AsyncTask<ConnecterClass, Long, JSONArray>
    {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(ConnecterClass... params) {
            // Execute in background

            return params[0].searchPlayers(school_id, sFName, sLName, sIDNum);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

            if (jsonArray != null) {

                setListViewArray(jsonArray);

                //login(edtEmail.getText().toString(),""
/*
                //Got to second screen if login is successful
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AfterLogin.class);

                //Pass the table name through
                intent.putExtra("CLIENT_DB", clientDB);

                startActivity(intent);

                */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XML - First Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginAcivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:hint="email ..."
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:hint="password ..."
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The XML - Second Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rohan.rohan_pc.sportsappv001.SearchActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Search"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Surname"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/edtLastName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtIDNum"
    android:hint="ID Number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtLastName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtLastName"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edtLastName" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edtIDNum"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/listViewSearch"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/edtIDNum"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edtFirstName"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
```

Comment: where's your second activity?

Comment: This is the second activity I did not post it as it is working hence I thought only where the problem seems to be I posted

Comment: Try if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}

Comment: @jms - I have tried what you suggested but no luck. It is really strange as to why one activity works and the other not. could it maybe have to do that I have a ListView adapter also?

Comment: And you had tried do this: android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: @jms yes I have done that also but I think it may be my android device as it worked on another android device

Comment: @user3772063 what device you have?

Comment: I am not sure what device I have some imported thing. but I figuredit it turns out it is not wise to just copy and paste the raw files to some other directory and working from that so I re-created the whole thing and everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

I just figured to re-create the app. I dont think it is a wise decision to copy the raw files to another directory and use that.